# How to highlight UITableVIewCell based on TabBar Badge Value iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to highlight the cell text based on tabbar badge value. As soon as user receive a notification i am displaying the badge count on the tabbar but after refreshing the view I want the cell to be highlighted based on present tabbar badge value. Please help me with this

[I want to achieve according to attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOhBH.png)

```
 let jsonObject = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)
            print(jsonObject)
            let responseDict:NSDictionary = jsonObject as! NSDictionary
            let messagesDictionary:NSDictionary? = responseDict.objectForKey("Data") as? NSDictionary

            appDelegate.messagesBadgeCount = messagesDictionary?.objectForKey("UnReadMessages") as! NSInteger

            if appDelegate.messagesBadgeCount > 0 {
                self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[0].badgeValue = String(appDelegate.messagesBadgeCount)
                if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items![0].badgeColor = UIColor(red: 219/255.0, green: 90/255.0, blue: 41/255.0, alpha: 1)
                } else {
                    // Fallback on earlier versions
                }

            }
```

I am getting the badge count from the JSON response but I don't have any identifier for particular cell weather its read or unread. Here I want highlight the top cell based on badge value and once user clicks on the cell I am calling didSelectRowAtIndexPath to clear up the tabbar badge value.
Here I want to clear both badge value and highlighted cell once didSelectRowAtIndexPath call.

Thanks in advance

Thanks @Koen I made following changes its working now but the highlighted text UITableViewCell returning for all cells. How can I restrict the highlighted cell count based on badge value

Made following changes in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
  if appDelegate.messageCount > 0 {

        if childDictionary is Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("UnReadMessageTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UnReadMessageTableViewCell

            cell.userIdChildLabel2.text = dictionary? ["UserId"] as? String
            cell.dateChildLabel2.text = dictionary? ["Date"] as? String
            cell.subjectChildLabel2.text = dictionary? ["ActivityText"] as? String
            cell.predicateChildLabel2.text = dictionary? ["Predicate"] as? String
            cell.activityChildLabel2.text = childDictionary? ["ActivityText"] as? String


            let modifiedDate = dictionary? ["Date"] as? String
            let modifiedTime = dictionary? ["Time"] as? String
            if modifiedTime != nil && modifiedDate != nil {
                let dateTime:String = modifiedDate! + " " + modifiedTime!
                cell.dateChildLabel2.text = getTimeZoneDate(dateTime)
            }
            if let imageView = dictionary? ["ProfilePicUrl"] as? String{
                cell.profileImageChildLabel2.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string:imageView ), placeholderImage : UIImage(named: "DefaultImage"))

            }
            return cell            
    }
```

Comment: some more clarification regarding where you want it and how,,unable to get a clear picture

Comment: Use a custom `UITableViewCell`, with a read-not read property; reload your table every time your response changes, and update the cells accordingly.

Comment: can you please eloborate little with code  Thanks !! @Koen

Comment: That is difficult without knowing the rest of your code and the structure of your app. I recommend to try this first yourself and if you get stuck, update your question.

Comment: Thanks @Koen !! I now I'm able to highlight the UITableViewCell but I am unable to restrict the return count based on badge value, here all the cells are highlighting

Comment: Use indexpath.row, if it is smaller than the badge count, highlight the cell, otherwise, don't.

Comment: Thanks @Koen Issue resolved